# Session destroyed while redirected from ccavenue

Tags: session, destroy, ccavenue

I have a problem with session being destroyed while the page is redirected in our site from CCavenue and this is session my main session for the cart and user also anybody have any idea about this matter.???

Comment: what language and framework are you using?

Comment: i had done code in Core PHP

Comment: Are you saving all cart information in session???